# The thermodynamics of Malthusian economics

Tags: thermodynamics, econo-physics

This question sits at the crossroad between economics and physics.

Given that

- The Earth receives a finite amount of light from the sun every day
- It can  dissipate a finite amount of heat and reflect a finite amount of light
- The amount of matter exchanged with space is comparatively irrelevant
- The set of all dissipative structures on Earth have to exist within that envelope

... and also given the laws of thermodynamics, even if the human economy switches entirely to non-fossil and non-nuclear energy, it won't be able to grow without gradually eating the share of non-industrial dissipative structures (be they biological, geological, oceanic or atmospheric), short of

- developing a space-based economy (which is in the realm of science fiction given the scale of the resources needed)
- inventing perpetual motion (which is in the realm of pure fantasy)

tl;dr: Perpetual growth within a finite daily energy budget seems impossible.

Is this assessment correct from a physics standpoint?

Comment: What is your specific definition of "perpetual growth"?

Comment: Which resources do you see as holding back a space-based economy? Is it really harder  than (or indeed anywhere near as hard as) using all of then energy the sun deposited on the earth's surface (see @JahanClaes comment)?

Comment: @JahanClaes the 2000 kcals are for food, you're ignoring shelter, curiosity, and other aspects of human nature that don't fit within these... I'm not talking about having too many humans, but about the mainstream economic dogma that prosperity can't be achieved without growing capital (i.e. industrial production capacity) at a *constant* rate...

Comment: @Malthus How does Jevons's paradox work in a command economy, out of curiosity? Are we implicitly assuming that the dominant economic structure of today will continue to be dominant indefinitely far into the future?

Comment: Not an economist, but IIUC, the Jevons paradox is a result of market forces that are not present in a planned economy. I wonder if there are economic models that enable distributed decisions, like the free market, but without its drawbacks (concentration of power over time, in so few hands that we end up with an economy planned by the rich for their own benefits)...

Comment: @Malthus Check the link I gave you. It explicitly demonstrates that, at least historically and probably into the future, we can have increased economic production with constant energy consumption. My point is that you can't specify how much  energy it takes to shelter humans or satisfy their curiosity, that depends on the current technology level. You can grow industrial capacity and shrink energy consumption.

Comment: @Malthus It's true that the developed world does currently consume a lot of energy for recreation, shelter, etc, but that's partly a function of energy being so cheap it's not worth optimizing over. But even in this cheap energy era we are getting more stuff out of each kwh every year!

Comment: @Jahan Energy is only cheap if you disregard the environmental debt we're accruing (e.g. in 120 years, ocean warming and acidification has destroyed 60+% of the vital phytoplankton around the world, and about the same share of the world's photosynthetic power).
We're also consuming more and more energy every year, despite the efficiency gains. While some of the world badly needs some economic growth, the brunt of it comes from the US (and the "west"; local energy consumption is dropping, but the production has just been outsourced https://www.indexmundi.com/facts/indicators/NE.RSB.GNFS.CD).

Comment: @JahanClaes your link has disappeared, and this is disingenuous. You can pursue *sigmoid* growth within a finite energy envelope provided the industry towards perpetual motion as fast as it grows. The current economic system and policies are predicated on perpetual exponential growth though. Also, the only way to improve efficiency is to automate (you can't optimize away these 2000 kcals), which strips individuals of their economic power. UBI? Sure, we broke your teeth, but we'll ship you Universal Biodegradable Incisors, every month, forever, pinky promise. It is not power, it is a decoy.

Comment: @Malthus I agree about the environmental debt, my point only requires energy to be "cheap" at the consumer level, even if it is artificially cheap! But increasing energy efficiency can lead to exponential growth, not just sigmoid growth. If you reduce the energy requirements by x% each year, you get exponential growth. My point is that currently, energy is "cheap," so we're not even really trying to optimize for energy efficiency. I don't KNOW if we can achieve exponential gains in energy efficiency year-on-year, but no-one can give a physics reason why it's impossible.

Comment: @Malthus Here is the link btw: https://www.eia.gov/todayinenergy/detail.php?id=10191. I will punt on the question of UBI, since I don't think it's what I was trying to address.

Comment: @JahanClaes To reduce the energy requirements in such a way, one needs to get rid of people somehow, doesn't one? Those 2000 kcals won't magically vanish, there's no room for optimization...

Comment: @JahanClaes My bad, I'm rusty at maths. You could have it grow exponentially on top of the constant amount needed to keep people alive.

Comment: @Malthus Fair enough, although I don't know that the 2000 calories is actually non-negotiable. There's probably room to engineer more efficient human body parts if it ever became a concern! But if your argument is that continuing exponential growth is ULTIMATELY unsustainable, I think the better argument is the eventual death of the sun, which will probably happen well before we reach $10^{16}$ humans!

Answer (score 1):

It is not impossible, though maybe not in the way that you intended.

Suppose that the amount of power consumed by humanity as a function of time (which is for all intents and purposes a continuous quantity) follows a logistic growth equation:

$$P(t)=\frac{C}{1+e^{-k(t-t_0)}}$$

If we take the derivative of this equation, then we get:

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=\frac{kCe^{-k(t-t_0)}}{(1+e^{-k(t-t_0)})^2}$$

You will notice one thing - the derivative is **always positive**. In other words, despite the fact that the power humanity uses in this model approaches some finite maximum value, humanity's power consumption is **perpetually growing** as a function of time.

If you don't like this answer, then you need to define specifically what you mean by the phrase "perpetual growth".

Comment: This is pretty astute, but AFAIU the mainstream economy therory predicates prosperity on having a cosntant relative growth rate, i.e. exponential growth.

What you're describing is more consistent with reality :-)

Comment: @Malthus Why wasn't that detail in the original question, then?

Comment: A total oversight on my end! But your answer is both technically correct given my approximate premises, and interesting, so I'm glad it turned out like that :-)